# is it bad practice to require php files rather than link to js and css?

Tags: php, javascript, css, require

I want to put snippets like these inside of a few php files and then require them in my main page, instead of using "pure" css and js files. I mean, I already do essentially this for my HTML DOM.

this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var foo = <?php echo $bar; ?>;
</script>
```

or this:

```
<style type='text/css'>
.foo{
background-image:url('<?php echo $bar; ?>image.png');
}
</style>
```

is that really bad practice?

and, if it is, what are the pros and cons of such an approach?

**Update:**

These days I'm just using Drupal which handles passing PHP variables to js in the theme system and supports CSS preprocessors like LESS and SASS. Both of the use cases I've raised in this question are handled pretty well by modern frameworks/preprocessors.

Comment: `foo` should be `.foo` or `#foo` :)

Comment: @Jonathan Not necessarily ... You can use Javascript to create tags I believe.

Comment: @Chacha: Sure, you could create a `foo` tag, but I doubt this is what the user had in mind :)

Comment: ok, it's .foo from now on! :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although CSS is not a problem, you'd have trouble if you wanted to send this as an HTTP response via AJAX.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var foo = <?php echo $bar; ?>;
</script>
```

AJAX won't allow Javascript for security reasons.

Best practice is to keep your Javascript in a separate file. That way client-side caching of the script will be to your advantage in terms of traffic too.

Comment: This is definitely the single biggest issue with what I suggested for the types of projects that I'm working on.

Thanks for the heads up! that would have been a pain to debug.

Answer (score 5):

Putting Javascript through the PHP interpreter is probably not a good idea. Likewise, CSS

- It encourages the antipattern of having server-side code writing client side code
- It makes it harder to test the JS and CSS in isolation (if they start being full of PHP code)
- It makes the PHP output bigger
- Clients will not cache part of a page, only a whole object

To expand on the last part - Javascript and CSS can get big (compared to HTML). If you have the client browser cache them, it does not need to download them.

True, including in the main document means there is no separate request which reduces overhead (particularly with SSL), but the client still needs to download the file. Having it coming from client cache is usually faster.

On the other hand, your code

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var foo = <?php echo $bar; ?>;
</script>
```

Looks like it's a piece of data, not Javascript code, so it might vary. You may also want to escape $bar correctly.

Comment: that seems pretty reasonable to me.

So it's not a flat "NO" because of a blatant security issue, it's more of a performance and development issue.

Both of those should be weighed up in the context of the project, and I think I can do that based on what you've said :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything necessarily bad about this. It's going to be an eye-sore for some people, but that's alright. Just be sure to keep this integration to a minimum, you really don't want a lot of php interspersed in your css, javascript, and html.

Comment: Heck with that! Make a `css.php` take takes the file as a GET parameter and parses tokens like `%varname%` into database-given ones! Over-complicating FTW!

Comment: it's not about overcomplicating. I'm using codeigniter as a framework and I'd love to use the base_url() function in my css to improve portability and reduce typing.

If I use relative urls my background images often don't appear when I edit the css using the firefox web developer addon.

It's the little things that make a difference..

Comment: @user278457 Relative paths in CSS shouldn't be an issue, since they're always served from the same directory. Including CSS with every page will actually make it much harder to deal with path issues. Get a decent CSS editor for the editing (CSSEdit for OS X). ;-P

Answer (score 0):

Following MarkR's thread (can't see how to reply to it), assuming you are just trying to pass data to JS:

One way you could gain the best of both worlds would be to include some logic in that PHP bit so that it checks for a certain cookie and for it to have a certain value (e.g. version/time). Like:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['warm']) && $_COOKIE['warm'] !== 'today') {
    echo '<script type=\'text/javascript\'>';
        echo "var foo = $bar;";
    echo '</script>';
}
```

The client side would first look for the foo global, and if it existed it would take that and cache it (e.g. localStorage) and set a cookie with the time or version or some property from the foo object. If foo was not present, then it would check the cache (e.g. localStorage). If it wasn't present there, then it would make an AJAX call for it.

This way you save the extra request on a cache miss/first time visitor, and gain a caching benefit on their repeats. Shouldn't go crazy with it, but I think it should be fine for small important data objects (bootstrap, user profile, dashboard info, etc).

(edit) To be clear, the central idea to keep this approach easily achievable and maintainable is to keep the server-side code that generates $bar for JS in one place that can be called both when PHP prints out var foo and when generating the JSON response. Likewise, the client side would use one function for parsing $bar, whether it came from the var, cache, or AJAX.